# How to include a row of a dataframe as part of an image

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to print the row of a dataframe below a plot. Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'px_last': 100 + np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()},
    index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=1000, freq='B'),
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)

# ax[0].plot(x,y,"k.")
# df.loc[idx, 'px_last'].plot(ax=ax, color=color, label='')
ax[0].plot(df.index, df['px_last'])
#url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kornelski/pngquant/master/test/img/test.png'
url = 'df_row1.png'
im = plt.imread(url)
implot = ax[1].imshow(im)
```

Right now, I save the first row of the dataframe as an image and plot it as a subplot for my main image. Is there an easier way to do this? I tried using `dataframe_image` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67572858/14022582) but it only saves the image, I'm unable to find a way to plot it dynamically as a subplot.

Here is my expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it seems that I can achieve this by using the table function of mpl. I don't know if it is possible to optimize the data frame you want to show, because it is difficult to control the details of the table function. I have modified your code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453531/matplotlib-table-formatting-column-width).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from pandas.plotting import table

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'px_last': 100 + np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()},
    index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=1000, freq='B'),
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)

ax[0].plot(df.index, df['px_last'])
tbl = table(ax[1], df.loc[[df.index[0]],:], loc='center', colWidths=[0.3 for x in df.columns])
# tbl.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(len(df.columns))))

plt.show()
```

[image]